# asymmetric random walk, hitting time probability

Tags: random-walks, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let's consider an asymmetric Random Walk on $Z$, with transition probabilities $p_{i, i+1}=p$, $~~p_{i, i+1}=q$, $\forall i \in \mathcal{Z}$, $p+q=1$ and $p>q$.

I am interested in the probability of the first hitting time of a bareer in $i=n$, assuming that the walk started from $i=0$ at time $t=0$. Is there an explicit formula for it? How does it depend on $n$?

Comment: This is an exercise. The reflection principle lets you count the walks which first arrive at $n$ at time $t$. These all have the same probability, since they all have $n$ more positive steps than negative steps.

Comment: This has been answered fully in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64919/biased-random-walk-and-pdf-of-time-of-first-return

Comment: The answer by Did suggests another solution by generating functions but the reflection method is much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explicit formula is: $P[N_m=n]=(m/n)P[S_n=m]$, where $P[N_m=n]$ is the
probability the position $m$ is hit after exactly $n$ steps, 
$S_n = X_1+X_2+\dots X_n$ and $P[S_n=m]$ is the probablity after $n$ steps
the path to be at the position $m$. This last is well-known and is given
by

$$P[S_n=m]=\frac{n!}{[(n+m)/2]![(n-m)/2]!}p^{(n+m)/2}q^{(n-m)/2}.$$

This is true when $n$ and $m$ have the same parity, else the probability
is zero. Additionally $m$ is positive and $n$ is greater than or equal to $m$.
A similar expression can be found for negative $m$.

Comment: A proof using reflection principle  [here , p.6](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf)

Comment: @C.C. (your link is broken, a copy is available on the wayback machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191126170213/http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf))